# using CFSTR() & UTF8String in objective C

Tags: objective-c

When converting NSString to constants, I usually use

```
[@"..." UTF8String];
```

I was just looking over apple docs on address book programming and i see they use the macro

```
CFSTR("...");
```

Out of curiousity, I'm just wondering is there any different between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CFSTR("...")` is essentially the Core Foundation equivalent of `@"..."`. In fact, you can do the following:

```
const char *utf8dots = [(NSString *)CFSTR("...") UTF8String];
```

And you'll get the same result as you would with your first line of code.

In theory, `CFSTR()` creates a constant `CFString`, while `@""` creates a constant `NSString`. In practice, the two types are interchangeable.

Does that help?

Comment: so basically, there is no practical difference in the value returned by CFSTR("foo") and the value returned by [@"foo" UTFTString] ?

Comment: No, re-read. There's no practical difference between `CFSTR("foo")` and `@"foo"`. `-UTF8String` can be sent to either and returns a third type of string, a C string encoded as UTF-8. That string isn't an object, it's a bare C pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Those create completely different sorts of things. One gets you a CFStringRef, which is an object (well, a CFType, but that's compatible with objects). The other gets you a char*, which is just an array of chars, and not an object at all. You could, for example, do this:

```
[(NSString *)CFSTR("foo") UTF8String];
```

and that would be totally valid.

Comment: so basically, there is no practical difference in the value returned by CFSTR("foo") and the value returned by [@"foo" UTFTString] ?

Comment: That's the opposite of what I said. There's no practical difference between CFSTR("foo") and @"foo". There's a HUGE difference between either of those, and the return value of -UTF8String

Answer (score 1):

The former doesn't actually create anything, it simply returns an internal `const char` pointer of an NSString (run-time function).  The latter will create a compile-time constant `CFStringRef` value.  It cannot be used with variables because those variables will not be available at compile time.

**EDIT** I realize that last sentence is a bit vague.  You can use the *result* of `CFSTR` as a variable, but you cannot pass a variable as an *argument*.

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot be used with variables" here?

Comment: If you try to insert a variable instead of a literal string you will get an error.